# Akra–Bazzi method for solving recurrences relation?

Tags: algorithm

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/4) + n
```

I'm not sure if this recurrences relation can be solved by Master theorem, but I found a easier way to do is using Akra–Bazzi method. Here, we have a1 = 1, b1 = 1/2, a2 = 1, b2 = 1/4, so solving p we have (1/2)^p + (1/4)^p = 1. So, p = 1, then using the formula, the asymptotic behavior can be determined as T(n) = θ(n + nlogn) = θ(nlogn)?

Comment: yes, it's right.

Comment: @OmG, actually my original equation has a typo, just edited. But does my solution still work? If we have a2 = 1 instead of 2.

Comment: No! Because p = 1 is not correct anymore!

Comment: Indeed, if we found p is < 1, what value of p should I plug into the formula.

Comment: it is the same.

Comment: Can you form a question in your title? It would really help. Also please use formatting

Answer (score 0):

It is not true. In the current state, `p = log(1 + sqrt(5))/log(2) - 1`. Hence,it would be `T(n) = Theta(n)` (see the details [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n%5E%28log%281%20%2B%20sqrt%285%29%29%2Flog%282%29%20-%201%29*%20%28integral%281%2Fx%5E%28log%281%20%2B%20sqrt%285%29%29%2Flog%282%29%20-%201%29%29%2C%20x%20from%201%20to%20n%29)).